# Ubuntu command-line window. A newbie question

Tags: command-line

I'm watching a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jzpkdYHwSQ) on youtube about `Zookeeper` installation, confuguration and usage. And what I do not understand is how the instructor opens up three different terminal windows with titles like `nuggetuser@HNHBMaster:~`, `nuggetuser@HNHRegion1:~` and `nuggetuser@HNHRegion2:~` [14:20]. When I open up a terminal window myself I always get the same title like `username@ubuntu:~`. So, please, explain what this stuff means (I mean those different terminals), so that I could proceed with `Zookeeper`. Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: He's probably using SSH to connect to different systems. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH

Comment: there is probably a terminal output sequence to set the terminal title. read the documentation of *your* terminal program for how to set it.

Comment: Well, I do not use any specific "my" terminal. It is a standard Ubuntu terminal which I open up with `ctrl + t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuggetuser@HNHBMaster` means that the username is `nuggetuser` and the host name of that computer is `HNHBMaster`.

If the other terminals show other hostnames it means that the user has logged onto another computer (most likely using ssh).